# using selenium without browser screen - python windows

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i use selenium for instagram appicatin.
i wonder there is any way to run selenium without browser opening in windows?
there is some solution in linux like install Xvfb but i don't see any solution for windows!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean that `--headless`?

You can do some operations without opening Chrome if you have chrome-driver.
Here is how to set `headless`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chromeoption = Options()
chromeoption.add_argument('--headless')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeoption)

# Then it is your work.
browser.get(url="xxx")
```

Comment: In order to use this code, it is obligatory to download the driver? Or does exist the way to use selenium without a driver? (I know collab version)

Comment: @shorenatevzadze No, you must download the driver AFAIK. The driver provide the API to make sure user could operate the browser.